# I don't know why my page doctype hang my chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, doctype

I have a very simple page , here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My IE8 and firefox has no problems.

I don't know why, my Chrome (version 35.0.1916.153 m) will hang, after loading the page. So when I mouse right click on it, it cannot show the right click menu.

Steps to reproduce the hang problem:

1. load the page
2. mouse right click on page (any empty space )
3. ....it will hang.

And then every time try to refresh this page, it will crash the page as screen captured here:
[image: chrome crashed]

Anyway, If I remove the <!DOCTYPE.....> tag, it will ok.

---

[you can click here to the test page](http://1st_programmer.sinatown.com/test.html)

---

But other page on the web is ok and never hang, they also has <!DOCTYPE.....> tag
eg. https://stackoverflow.com/

---

[<!DOCTYPE html>](http://1st_programmer.sinatown.com/test2.html)

[<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">](http://1st_programmer.sinatown.com/test3.html)

This two also hang my chrome.

---

### Thanks you all, it is embarrassing that my chrome installation has problem, I think this question should be closed. Thanks again for providing comments and answers.

(How to self closed?)

Comment: Try `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Pinal That's for HTML5. The OP (apparently) wants XHTML.

Comment: @Pinal I try it too on  http://1st_programmer.sinatown.com/test2.html but also fail.

Comment: @Juhana In fact I can use html4 only, so I can even remove the doctype. but I just don't understand why it will hang, but other webpage will not hang eg. stackoverflow.com , thanks you

Comment: It might be worth removing and reinstalling Chrome on your computer. I have the exact same Chrome version, and have no problem with that HTML.

Comment: @ScottLeis Yes! you seem correct! I just install a PortableApp Chrome (same version 35.0.1916.153 m), it run without problem!!!! Because my Windows 7 is protected by my office Admin, I can only install my Chrome(which has problem) by non-admin right. it is the root of problems?

Comment: I don't know, but I suppose that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all, it is embarrassing that my chrome installation has problem, I think this question should be closed. Thanks again for providing comments and answers.

Answer (score -2):

I cant experience the error you are having so maybe try HTML 5 tag

```
<!doctype html>
```

but since it isnt a standard yet I don't know maybe try html4.01 strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Sorry I'm not much help

Comment: http://1st_programmer.sinatown.com/test3.html it is also hang. on the other hand, I am sorry I am not saying how to reproduce the "hang" correctly. I will edit my post now.

Comment: "[HTML5] isn't a standard yet" is quite a frivolous claim. Anything to back it up?

Comment: @Juhana http://www.w3.org/blog/2012/12/html5-smile-its-a-snapshot/ <- this is when they published the candidate recomendation

Comment: Yes, for **HTML 5.1**. That doesn't mean that HTML 5.0 is not standard. (In fact it even implies it, because they wouldn't be working on 5.1 if 5.0 weren't stable.)

Comment: In any case, there's a difference between an "official" standard and a de facto standard -- in practice all modern browsers support HTML 5, or at least they shouldn't crash when they see the doctype.

Comment: Thanks all, the reason is my chrome has problem. anyway I also agree with @JB567 , the HTML5 is not standardized yet. Anyway HTML5 has many great features, hope W3 will hurry up.

Comment: @Juhana yes, you are right too. html5 is de facto standard today, many web/mobile application cannot live without it. You are correct too. Thanks to MDN, we can avoid any compatible problems by reading MDN.

Comment: @Juhana what I was trying to say is it isn't fully supported by all browsers or officially standardized by the W3C. So there can potentially be discrepancies or issues with cross-browser support. I agree that is basically the norm for html at the moment but Bernes-Lee wants HTML5 to be perfect

Comment: "Not fully supported" means that some semantic tags don't bring in extra functionality; just including the doctype doesn't cause browser crashes.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem just as of today, 7/5/18, on pages I've had no issues with until now. My chrome browser has an update that needs to install, but it seems odd that pages that were working fine 2 days ago suddenly aren't. In the console it is throwing "Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier" and my html tag is `<!doctype html>`. Very strange. We'll see if updating chrome fixes the issue, but know that you are not alone in experiencing this bug.